# Xamarin Stuck Building Archive

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

When building my Xamarin project, it gets to this part of the build process and hangs forever. Left it overnight only to find it sitting in the same spot in the morning.

```
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native assembler: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-as"   -o obj\Release\110\aot\arm64-v8a\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll\temp.s.o obj\Release\110\aot\arm64-v8a\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll\temp.s
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native linker: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-ld" -Bsymbolic -shared -o obj\Release\110\aot\arm64-v8a\libaot-Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll.so.tmp  obj\Release\110\aot\arm64-v8a\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll\temp.s.o 
[aot-compiler stdout] JIT time: 139 ms, Generation time: 1707 ms, Assembly+Link time: 612 ms.
```

Is there somewhere else I can look to see if there are actual errors occurring, which might be causing the issue?  App will run on emulator fine in Debug mode, but this happens when building in Release.

Note, that on occasion I can get it to complete, but not consistently.

In Archive Manager, the green bar just keeps scrolling, showing "packaging" of the app.

These are the configurations of the two builds:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    <AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>false</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>true</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    <AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>false</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    <AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidKeyStore>false</AndroidKeyStore>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is it possibly an R8 issue?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2022? I've been having similar problems with it, however, the app builds just fine using either VS 2019 or a command to build it with msbuild.

Comment: I believe you could get more verbose output by going to **Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Build And Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity** and setting the verbosity to a higher value. Or calling the msbuild directly with a verbosity specified.

Comment: Using 2019. I'll check out that verbose output, thanks

Comment: Any update for this case?

Comment: Nope. Still haven't worked it out. But clearing the .vs folder seemed to work the last time it happened

Comment: It's so strange. But cleaning the .vs folder maybe a workaround.